# Getting a 100k Thermistor to read properly

Tags: power-supply, thermistor, heater

I built a 3D printer with a build space of 600mm x 600mm x 900 mm. My heat bed has a 100k Thermistor built into it, initially I could not get it to read properly seeing as how it was only a 2 pin connection and the connection required at least 3 pins.
So I wired in a 4.7 k ohm resistor into the thermistor along with a third wire as seen in the picture below.

Now I ran this with a 12 V 750 W ATX, and the thermistor read properly but the heatbed and the extruders were unable to heat up for they require 24 Volts. The heatbed is wired into the main using a 25 amp DC SSR.

I replaced the ATX with a 24 V 1200 W  50 amp power supply. Now my heat bed heats up as do my dual extruders but the 100k Thermistor built into the heat bed doesn't read properly. The Thermistor keeps fluctuating in every direction about -10°C to +5°C causing my heat bed to heat inconsistently and continue heating after the necessary temperature has been reached.

My question is, what do I need to do to get the thermistor to read properly and steady and why did it read with the 12v 750 w atx but not with the 24 V 1200 w power supply?

[image]

Comment: It might be electrical noise (EMI) from the switching power supply. The ATC supply is grounded and may have better EMI control. You can try putting a 0.1uF-1uF ceramic capacitor across the thermistor at the Arduino end.

Comment: How did Jeremy Blum recommend that it be wired up? "*So I wired in a 4.7 k ohm resistor into the thermistor along with a third wire ...*" Why? Are you guessing or did you have a reason? "*Thermistor built into the heat bed doesn't read properly.*" What does it read? What is the voltage across it? What should that voltage be? You'd need to supply the schematic for the temperature control section along with details of what you've actually done. The green blob on your diagram is neatly obstructing the red text below it. Is the thermistor separate from the 24 V supply?